# Azure ADB2C request token for service

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

### Context

I understand Azure AD B2C has a limitation on the oauth2 `client_credentials` flow, but I've seen that it is possible to request the token agains the AD instead of AD B2C.

For what I understand this is a change on the **authority domain**, so instead of using:

```
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

We should use:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/032bba1a-4a23-41d0-8713-69ad1a38cf69/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

---

### Problem

My problem is that if I add a scope to it, like `https://graph.microsoft.com/openid/.default` or other from a different application (which is the one I intend to use) `https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/backendtestapi/api/.default`, I get this error:

```
AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/openid was not found in the tenant named xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant
```

I'm not understanding why there's an error If I request this scopes. Can anyone enlighten me please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That scope is invalid. Follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token. For a custom app and scope, it should be in this format `https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/something/something/.default` - it gives the exact value in the menu.

Comment: What's the difference between: `https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/something/something/.default` and `https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/backendtestapi/api/.default`? Can't understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Microsoft Graph is the official API whose `scope` has a fixed writing format `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` for V2.0.

Changing `https://graph.microsoft.com/openid/.default` to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` can resolve this issue and you will get an access token for calling Microsoft Graph API.

If you has your own custom Web API which requires client credentials flow, you should expose the API in your API app registration by following [Exposing application permissions (app roles)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#if-your-web-api-is-called-by-a-daemon-app). And then configure the application permission in your client app registration by following [Add permissions to access your web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-your-web-api).

After that you could get the `scope` format. Typically it's `api://{app id of the API app registration}/.default`. If you customize the Application ID URI of API app registration as `https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/backendtestapi/api/`, then the `scope` should be `https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/backendtestapi/api/.default`.

But there is an important thing you need to understand. It's that since client credentials flow issues an application token without user, it has nothing to do with B2C authentication in this case. In other words, you just 'borrow' the B2C tenant to create the app registration. B2C is not used for identity authentication.

BTW, application permission usually requires admin consent. Don't forget to click on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}" on client app registration or [use the adminconsent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what you said, but if I try to ask for the API permission when authenticating agains the `login.microsoftonline.com` authority, I get an error of that permission not being available in that tenant. Does that make sense? Thanks

Comment: @JohnySerpa Did you create the API app registration by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#register-the-web-api? And if you are using a multi-tenant app, you should use admin consent endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of other tenant}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}` to add the app into other tenant.

Comment: should the API be a B2C app or not? I mean, should I choose the last option "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)" when creating an App through AD B2C?
I'm confused with that one. My frontend app is a B2C and it must be to authenticate users. But my backend app, I'm not sure if it must be a B2C app as well. Thanks

Comment: @JohnySerpa No. It's unnecessary to choose the B2C app.

Comment: I think I need it to be. Otherwise I get an error of `authentication failed due to: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: We did not receive a token we know how to validate`. I don't think I can validate a B2C token in an non-B2C app. Can you tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: If you use AN B2C app for API, everything is OK? But in my experience, B2C app is used in user flow.